# What is the best way to pass series of data to QML (from python)

Tags: python, qml, pyside, qtcharts

I need to pass *x,y* data (computed in python) to **Qt Charts** (using **QML**) and plot it. I can use **Signal** and slot with arguments (int, bool, string) but can not use it with array or list. Is that even possible?
Maybe the better way to pass my data from python to **QML** would be through some file (csv,txt) - python saves *x,y* data and **QML** will read it and plot it? Is that even possible?

The total goal of my question is directed to ploting data (from python) in **Qt Charts** (**QML** and Qt Creator).

Thank you for any help. I am newbie in that..

Comment: Sounds like you want some type of [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Comment: @JarMan Thank you for direct me. I found this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-modeldata-example.html). But need to find some python example. From this (as newbie) I am not able to implement it to my python/QML code. Also if I understand correctly in the example is not any QML code?

Comment: I don't use python myself, so I can't help you there. But [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-modeldata-example.html) example demonstrates how to construct the model. That part works the same way in widgets and QML. It uses a QVXYModelMapper object to use the model as a data source for the chart. You can do the same thing in QML with a [VXYModelMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-vxymodelmapper.html).