# How to plot data in QML Qt Charts (with python)

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtcharts

I want to plot data in **Qt charts** (**QML**) from **python**. The *x,y* data are saved in array `x = np.array([0, 6]) y = np.array([0, 250])` . I am desperate how to pass these data to Qt Charts with one step. I can do it (step by step) with Signal/Slot, where the Signal is with parameters (x,y).

My working (very slow) code:

Creating signal from python to qml:

```
class AppWindow(QObject):

    # Signals from python to QML
    sigPlotData = Signal(int, int, arguments=['x','y'])
```

and later () I generate and send data to chart like that:

```
...      
for i in range(50):
   self.app.sigPlotData.emit(i, random.randint(0,150))
...
```

In QML file I do this:

```
 //connections from Python to QML via signals
    Connections {
        target: backend

        function onSigPlotData(x,y){
          
            lineSer.append(x, y);
        }
    }
```

---

```
ChartView {
 id: chartView
 title: "Line"
 anchors.fill: parent

ValueAxis{
     id: axisX
     min: 0
     max: maxX
     }

 ValueAxis{
    id: axisY
    min: 0
    max: 150
  }

 LineSeries {
 id: lineSer
 name: "data"
 axisX: axisX
 axisY: axisY
 }
}
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: This looks like a more detailed form of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73170743/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-series-of-data-to-qml-from-python). Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 2):

you can have this :

in **main.py** :

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(
        handle_object_created, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and in `main.qml` :

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtCharts 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 300
    property int timeStep: 0

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 400
        }

        LineSeries {
            id: series1
            axisX: axisX
            name: "data"
        }

    }

    Timer {
        interval: 100
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            timeStep++;
            var y = (1+Math.cos(timeStep/10.0))/2.0;
            series1.append(timeStep, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result is:**

[image]

**In QML you can create your function or other things like(for, if,..) with javascript syntax**

and as you see I use `series1.append(timeStep, y);` means **append** function for adding data.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This is almost the same solution as I posted. Problem is that I need to plot it in one step (because this is slow). My data can have 10000 points. I tried to series1.append(someListX,someListY) but it does not worked for me.